# [GLPI][Generic Object] Item list

Tags: list

I'm currently learning to use GLPI with Generic Object Management.
My company need to keep track of some production machine so I've created a new object and it works fine.

Now, we need to make a "group" of machine, I mean link them together, so that when one is under maintenance, we know the ones that work together with it are also stopped.

So, I wonder if there is a way of making a list of element just as the email list in the user form, where you can add one or several email. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not featured on current Generic Object plugin and will require some coding.
I understand you need something like a Computer Cluster. I will ask on the repository:
https://github.com/pluginsGLPI/genericobject/issues/new
In the past, we have made a custom dev for a Father-Son modification. The thing here is you need to commit into maintaining it if it is not accepted in the official repository.
https://github.com/pluginsGLPI/genericobject/

Cheers,